# How can a method in a superclass be redefined for all subclasses?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Let's say I have classes like this:

```
class One
  def my_method
    puts 1
  end
end

class Two < One
end

class Three < One
end
```

Then I want to redefine my_method in one place so it applies to all three classes. Is this possible, either with monkeypatching or some other method?

Comment: Why  don't you just change the method  in your `One` class? Then, it would be inherited by all  child classes automatically.

Comment: You just change One#my_method. Since it's inherited and not defined in your other classes, method lookup will follow the ancestor chain to call the updated method.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that inheritance causes `my_method` to be _copied_ from `One` into the subclasses. But this isn’t true: it only exists in `One` and changing it there will reflect the change everywhere else. See the docs for [Method Lookup](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup).

Comment: Are you trying to redefine the method at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Monkeypatching this should work:

```rb
class A
  def hello
    "Hello"
  end
end

class B < A; end

class C < A; end

c = C.new

c.hello # > "Hello"

class A
  def hello # Monkeypatching A to change `hello`.
    "Goodbye"
  end
end

# Hello returns a new value, even though it's an instance of C
c.hello # > "Goodbye"
```